# DataFrame to CSV in a for loop with different file names

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

I am creating pandas DataFrames in a for loop and I would like to save them in csv files with different names at each iteration of the for loop.

I know how to save one DataFrame:

```
path = r"C:\Users\SessionName\FolderName\FileName.csv"
df.to_csv(path)
```

Now when I have a list of strings, e.g.

```
countries = ['United States', 'China', 'Russia', 'India']
```

I would like the four files to be named `United States_ranking.csv`, `China_ranking.csv`, etc.

I have tried:

```
for country in countries:
    path = r"C:\Users\SessionName\FolderName\" + country + "_ranking.csv"
```

But is won't work.

Comment: do you want the csvs to be exactly the same ? is there a country column you can group on first ?

Comment: Do you have the "df.to_cvs(path)" line inside your for-loop?

Comment: ...and lower-case 'f' in "for".

Comment: @Carl yes I do!
Corrected the 'F'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
for country in countries:
    path = r"C:\\Users\\SessionName\\FolderName\\ {} _ranking.csv".format(country)
```

Answer (score 2):

personally, I would use `pathlib` to handle your paths. also be careful for typos in your code.

for example,

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

src_path  = r"C:\Users\SessionName\FolderName\FileName.csv"
countries = ['United States', 'China', 'Russia', 'India']

for country in countries:
    p = Path(src_path).parent.joinpath(f"{country}_ranking.csv")
    df.to_csv(p,index=False)
```

---

this will write:

```
C:\Users\SessionName\FolderName\United States_ranking.csv
C:\Users\SessionName\FolderName\China_ranking.csv
C:\Users\SessionName\FolderName\Russia_ranking.csv
C:\Users\SessionName\FolderName\India_ranking.csv
```

---

The benefit of having a pathlib object here is that you can check if the directory is valid or if the file exists before hand.

```
print(p)
WindowsPath('C:/Users/SessionName/FolderName/United States_ranking.csv')
if not p.is_file():
   df.to_csv(p,index=False)
else:
    print('file exists')
```

Comment: @jezrael I think so too, but OP hasn't shown the structure of CSV so don't want to assume

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the path like this, otherwise it causes a problem with `"\"`

```
for country in countries:
    path = r"C:\\Users\\SessionName\\FolderName\\" + country + "_ranking.csv"
```

Comment: He/she uses a raw string, so thats not it.

Comment: No, the raw string doesn't work for strings which end with one '\'.

Comment: Aha! I see. I was not aware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer os.path.join(folder, country+filename)

```py
for country in countries:
    path = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\SessionName\\FolderName\\", country + "_ranking.csv")
    df.loc[df.country == country].to_csv(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like rawstring dont work with `"\"` and the end of the string.

You can fix it by adding extra \ after your path to folder by puting double `"\\"` in another string.

```
countries = ['United States', 'China', 'Russia', 'India']
for country in countries:
    path = r"C:\Users\SessionName\FolderName" + "\\" + country + "_ranking.csv"
```